# More on algebraic and orthogonal complements

Tags: functional-analysis

Is there a theorem that states that if $H$ is an inner product space then if $C$ is a closed subspace then the algebraic complement and the orthogonal complement of $C$ coincide?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081500/let-s-be-a-closed-subspace-of-an-inner-product-space-h-is-it-true-that-h

Comment: There is no such thing as "*the* algebraic complement". There are many spaces that are algebraic complements. Think of $H$ being the plane and $C$ a line in it: any other line (passing through the origin) is a complement of $C$. It need not be orthogonal.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Yes right, sorry, I meant to write an algebraic complement.

Comment: So... if you realize that there are many algebraic complements, yet there is just one orthogonal complement, then you should know the answer to your question.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Yes, thank you, I realised it right when I was about to edit my question once more.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat I see it more clearly now. Perhaps I wanted to ask this question with dimensions, that is, when the dimensions of the orthogonal and algebraic complements agree. Is it better to delete this one here and make a new one or better to edit?

Comment: Dimension is additive under direct sums. So, if $H$ is finite dimensional, then its dimension is equal to the sum of dimensions of $C$ and of any of its complement. This implies that all algebraic complements of $C$ have the same dimension. And one of them is the orthogonal complement.